# How to limit port 80 to just one user with iptables

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, port80

I want to limit port 80 so that only one user can use it. I want to do this with iptables I have not found any documentation on how to do this.

Comment: What's a user? You mean single source IP address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean "a local user with a discrete uid" then you can use the owner module (`-m owner`) and the `--uid-owner #` option.

But there are some problems here:

1. This only works on outbound packets.
2. Some packets don't have owners.

By themselves, those might not normally be deal-breakers. But you need to effectively invert the conditional and block packets not matching the user. I suspect this will sufficiently break protocol processing that a simple attempt to do this will fail.

I would say, forward port 80 output that you know will have a user association to a separate chain, and then filter only that chain by user. This should sufficiently break other user's traffic but not internal traffic to generally meet your requirement.

Comment: I'm only worrying about outbound, because I only want to block request's from being made, and if request are blocked, then how will there be any incomming response. Could you give the command that I would need to use? I don't have much experience with iptables.

Answer (score 1):

iptables has the `-m owner --uid-owner ###` match which "Matches if the packet was created by a process with the given effective user id"